# Determine problem in CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've created a base controller that all of my controllers extend...

```
class PublicController extends CI_Controller {
    private $js = array(),
            $css = array(),
            $templateVars = array();

    public function __construct () {
        parent::__construct();

        //register account
        $this->templateVars['account'] = ($this->account = $this->modelFactory('account'));

        // enable profiler for development
        if (ENVIRONMENT == 'development') {
            $this->output->enable_profiler(true);
            $this->addJs('jquery-min-1.5.2');
        } else {
            $this->addJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js');
        }

        $this->addCss('base');
        $this->addJs('base');
    }


/**
 * Loads and initiates models
 */
protected function modelFactory ($model, $input = array()) {
    $this->load->model($model);

    $class = $model.'Model';
    return new $class($input);
}
```

The problem here is that I get the error `Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\site.com\system\core\Common.php on line 328`

When I comment out the line `$this->templateVars['account'] =` the error goes away.... how come this is looping?

Comment: Hot tip: `$this->templateVars['account'] = ($this->account = $this->modelFactory('account'));` can just be written as `$this->templateVars['account'] = $this->account = $this->modelFactory('account');`. Kinda just preference I guess.

Comment: Try calling `$this-modelFactory('account');` by itself and see what happens, I'd say your problem lies in there.

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code from `system/core/Common.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you could add this as the first statement in your __construct method:

```
 global $onlyonce; if ($onlyonce++) return;
```

This will prevent multiple instances of your controller to be created. Without knowing the rest of your code, or CodeIgniter, it's likely to assume that your model class itself instantiates your controller. Which in turn creates another model.

A xdebug profiler trace will tell you more. This is not enough code to tell you the exact reason.

Comment: Mario - that worked perfectly, thanks!  It's weird, because the model doesn't do anything with the controller the best I can tell... thanks

Comment: But take care that this is just an example workaround. You must rewrite it to use a static class variable at least. And you should look for the actual problem source still.

Comment: I have posted on the CI forums for assistance in determining the cause.... static is a good call, thanks

Answer (score 1):

@webnet it happened the same to me in an CI with modules (HMVC). My controller had the same file name of the model. Changing the name did the trick.